# Install QGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: qgis, installation

How can I install new version of QGIS (2.0)?

When I try with the indication of the official web site of QGIS, terminal write me that the last version of QGIS (1.7.5 wrowclaw) has several plugins that not permise it.

I am a new user of ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Where did you fail? What errors pop up? What sources did you use for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem a while ago. The answers explain the installation pretty well!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/351899/qgis-quantum-gis-install-fails-unmet-dependencies